# What is the procedure for installing a print driver for an Epson ET-16500 printer?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner

I need help installing a driver for my Epson ET-16500 printer.  Epson has the drivers on their website, but they don't include instructions on how to install them on Ubuntu Linux.  I'd like to be able to print and scan (if possible).  Is there a tutorial on how to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a manual at the Epson site.

Answer (score 0):

Download deb files from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

according to your arch (i386 or amd64), copy them to your Home directory and install them using

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If you get error messages regarding unmet dependencies, run

```
sudo apt install -f
```

There are both printer and scanner drivers for your printer.

The scanner driver is now provided as a directory with some deb files and an install script. You can either copy the deb files from there as I mentioned before, or use the install script with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I've since found a tutorial that resolved my issue.  I'm now able to print and scan within Ubuntu.  It took a few tries.  Somewhat of a blur as I had to download, run a few scripts and installers in a certain order.  Nevertheless, it's working to my expectations.  Not as many (printing/scanning) options as my Windows 10 PC, but enough to suit my needs.  Now, if I could just figure out how to get the drivers to work with my Raspberry Pi 2...?

Cheers.

Comment: What options are you missing? You probably can't find where you set them up, or you did not install the drivers.

Comment: Most of the options are the same.  At a glance, I see that multi page per sheet, presets,  Ink Levels, Maintenance aren't available. I use multi page per sheet now and again, so I wish that were included.  I can use my PC for the other options.

Comment: Inc levels and maintenance is available in `epson-printer-utility`.